# OpenCV update messing up CaptureFromCAM on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, unix, opencv, raspberry-pi, v4l2

I recently updated my opencv to version 2.4.6.1 . and i installed with following commands and settings on my raspberry pi.

```
wget downloads.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-unix/2.3.1/OpenCV-2.4.6.1.tar.gz
tar -xvf OpenCV-2.4.6.1.tar.gz
cd OpenCV-2.4.6.1/
cmake -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
make
sudo make install
```

I have uv4l drivers for my Pi and they worked properly for previous version as far as capture is concerned. Now the same program which worked fine is not working in the updated version. I checked the width and height of the capture . They are both -1 . What should I do to make the camera capture work?. The main reason I did the update is because I was getting only 64x64 thumbnails from my previous version of opencv capture. Suggest me a way. And also could it be related to raspberry pi (Is a firmware update necessary after updating opencv ?)

Answer (score 0):

I've heard a lot of people say that updating the firmware by doing rpi-update fixed the problem.